# Get list of countries where postal code is optional - magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to programatically get the list of countries where postcode is optional. These are set at the back-end in magento. (System->Configuration->Country Options).

Up to now, I've haven't found anything useful. Any clues how this could be done?

Thanks!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 2):

The directory helper contains a handy method to retrieve these country codes as an array (or json if you pass in true):

```
Mage::helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip()
```

You can also use getStoreConfig to retrieve the values - though this will give you a comma separated string which you will probably end up turning in to an array anyway to deal with:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/optional_zip_countries')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found how. `Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/optional_zip_countries')` gets the list of country codes having an optional postcode.